# How do I document overloaded functions?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsdoc

I have 2 functions (actually 1 function that checks arg types):

```
moveTo(x, y, opts)
moveTo(point, opts)
```

The `opts` is an object that has long documentation like this

```
 /*
 * .... 
 * @param {object} [opts] An object containing additional options
 * @param {number} [opts.opt1] desc1
 * @param {boolean} [opts.opt2] desc2
 */
```

How do I properly document this function using jsdoc?

I know I could use a trick and copy all `opts` definitions onto `y` argument:

```
* @param {number|object} [y] ...
```

but that would be really ugly. Is there another way?

Comment: I've never used it, but a quick look around seems that you can repeat the entire jsdoc comment block for each overload - have you tried that at all, see what it ends up generating?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I'm using it for IntelliJ IDEA autocomplete. In that case it uses only the last definition. Probably documentation generators will work well with your suggestion.

Comment: Right, in that case I'd be tempted to dig about in its settings (I use resharper inside VS, I guess their IDE is pretty configurable also?) - there may be something there.  If not, perhaps raise it as a bug/feature request with them.

Comment: Looks like there's been [a couple](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8744) of different [issues logged](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21129) with them for webstorm over time, so I guess it's something they're aware of - perhaps some prompting might get them to also work on IntelliJ also.